# miniz.c getting "already defined" errors in VS

Tags: c++, visual-c++

After adding miniz.c to the project and including it:

```
#include "miniz.c"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

The linker spits out a huge amount of "already defined" errors.

```
1>  miniz.c
1>  Source.cpp
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_extract_archive_file_to_heap already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_end already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_finalize_heap_archive already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_finalize_archive already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_add_from_zip_reader already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_add_file already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_add_mem_ex already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_add_mem already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_init_from_reader already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_init_file already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_init_heap already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_writer_init already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_file already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_end already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_file already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_callback already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_callback already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_heap already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_heap already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_mem already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_mem already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_mem_no_alloc already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_extract_to_mem_no_alloc already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_locate_file already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_get_filename already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_file_stat already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_is_file_a_directory already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_is_file_encrypted already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_get_num_files already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_init_file already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_init_mem already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_zip_reader_init already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_write_image_to_png_file_in_memory already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_write_image_to_png_file_in_memory_ex already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_create_comp_flags_from_zip_params already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_compress_mem_to_mem already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_compress_mem_to_heap already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_compress_mem_to_output already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_get_adler32 already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_get_prev_return_status already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_init already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_compress_buffer already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tdefl_compress already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tinfl_decompress_mem_to_callback already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tinfl_decompress_mem_to_mem already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tinfl_decompress_mem_to_heap already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _tinfl_decompress already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_error already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_uncompress already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_inflateEnd already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_inflate already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_inflateInit already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_inflateInit2 already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_compressBound already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_compress already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_compress2 already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_deflateBound already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_deflateEnd already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_deflate already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_deflateReset already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_deflateInit2 already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_deflateInit already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_version already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_free already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_crc32 already defined in miniz.obj
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _mz_adler32 already defined in miniz.obj
```

Link to miniz.c for those who are not familiar with the library https://code.google.com/p/miniz/

Comment: You're forgetting a necessary `#define` before including the source file.

Comment: From the comments in miniz.c `* This is a header file library, like stb_image.c. To get only a header file, either cut and paste the
below header, or create miniz.h, #define MINIZ_HEADER_FILE_ONLY, and then include miniz.c from it.`

Comment: @user1095108 `#define MINIZ_HEADER_FILE_ONLY` as it looks like, to be precise.

Answer (score 9):

**Never, ever** include source files! They aren't intended to do so.

Separate declarations in a header file `.h` and definitions in the `.c` file.

Include the header file anywhere you need to refer to the declarations.

---

As for your particular case you should have included the `miniz.c` as follows

```
#define MINIZ_HEADER_FILE_ONLY
#include "miniz.c"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

This is documented in the `miniz.c` file itself (at line 928)

```
// ------------------- End of Header: Implementation follows. 
// (If you only want the header, define MINIZ_HEADER_FILE_ONLY.)
```

Comment: miniz doesn't have a header file. In the example they include miniz.c directly.

Comment: @Cshark: You included it multiple times...

Comment: Don't think so. The only two files in my project are: miniz.c and source.c which contains only the code seen above.

Comment: @Cshark `After adding miniz.c to the project`  Don't add it to your project.   All of the source code is in that "header" (why the author decided to do things this way, I have no idea).

Comment: @Cshark As you have these two files in your project they'll both probably compiled and linked automatically from your whatever IDE's build system. Thus you have it compiled twice (once with the inclusion from `source.c` and once as `miniz.c` itself. Exclude `miniz.c` from your compiled sources if you insist doing as you do.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use this crazily designed library as the author (apperently) intends, you'll need to:

- only include it from one source file - all access to the library will have to go through that file.
- don't also compile and link the library; its definitions are already in the file that included it. Don't add it to the project, or find a way to tell the IDE that it shouldn't be treated as a source file.
- don't use if you're writing a library, as that would prevent any program using your library from also using this one.

Alternatively, you could write your own header containing the library's declarations, include that instead of the `.c` file, and compile and link the library as a normal source file. Or you could look for a library written by someone who understands the compilation model.